# Can I get iFrame form contents via a hot-linked script if both are on my same domain but implemented on a third party?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a domain like mine.com which has a JS file on it (mine.com/some.js) and has an iFrame form (mine.com/form/) that people can submit.  My clients put a link to the the JS file on their site (which itself injects the iFrame) such as `<script src='https://mine.com/some.js'></script>`) but since the JS file is still on MY domain, can I use that script to read the form's contents?

I understand that their domain cannot read the contents of the iFrame, but since the script itself is hosted on my domain is there a way to authorize this?

Comment: No. What matters is the domain of the top-level page that loads the script.

Comment: You can potentially work something out via [inter-frame message posting, however.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)